# create a dataframe or tibble based on values in different rows in another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a column of event time offsets (ms) like this (but much bigger)

```
> ts_data = tibble( t = c(34, 78, 111, 165, 189))
> ts_data
# A tibble: 5 x 1
      t
  <dbl>
1    34
2    78
3   111
4   165
5   189
```

and I'd like to create a second column where the value in each row is the difference between the current row and the previous one (assuming t=0 at the start). So (by hand) for the above data I want to end up with this ..

```
> add_column(ts_data, t_int = c(34, 44, 33, 54, 24))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      t t_int
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    34    34
2    78    44
3   111    33
4   165    54
5   189    24
```

i.e. 44 = 78-34; 33 = 111-78,...

I could do something with a loop but was sort of expecting that there might be a neater way using relative indexing however my quest to date has yet to bear fruit.

Any pointers would be appreciated :-)

Comment: I think the last value is 24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier option with `diff` which returns a `vector` of `length` one less than the original `vector` (or column).  So, append the `first` value of 't' to create the `length` equal as that of the original column

```
library(dplyr)
ts_data %>% 
   mutate(t_int = c(first(t), diff(t)))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#      t t_int
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1    34    34
#2    78    44
#3   111    33
#4   165    54
#5   189    24
```

---

Or take the difference of the original column with the `lag` of the column specifying the `default` as 0 (by default it is `NA`)

```
ts_data %>%
      mutate(t_int = t - lag(t, default = 0))
```

Comment: for info for possible future readers, I now realise I should have searched for 'r time series'